# Setup Listview to strikethrough item after click

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener

good day, i have a problem here with my listview

1. i have a listview with custom arrayadapter which is have 12 item
2. i have already set the listview when click it's get strikethrough on the selected item

**UPDATE**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView mainList;
    private final String[] listContent = {
            "1. Get Ready",
            "2. Second ",
            "3. Third",
            "4. Fourth",
            "5. Fifth",
            "6. Sixth",
            "7. Seventh",
            "8. Eight",
            "9. Nineth",
            "10. Ten",
            "11. Eleven",
            "12. Twelve",
            "13. Look up number twelve",
            "14. Its become strikethrough too",
            "15. how to fix it?",
            "16. Please help",
            "17. Thanks",
            "18. End" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mainList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview2);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listContent);
        mainList.setAdapter(adapter);

        mainList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                TextView text = (TextView) view;
                text.setPaintFlags(text.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
            }

        });
    }
}
```

my problem is, when i click the first item (number one) and then it become strikethrough but the 12 item (number twelve) it's also strikethrough to.
see my picture

clicking first item:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0nvm.jpg

number twelve also get strikethrough
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hTPM.jpg

Comment: without code nobody can help you.

Comment: sorry, i'm forget to add, i update my post

Comment: add some item to list and repeat to check if 23 get breakthrough too.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I also face same problem here with listView. Can anybody give the solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is because it is the same View instance that is being used now that the first item is out of view.

For this purpose you will need to implement your own [(Base)Adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) and store the information there as to which items should be strike through.
Then set the correct paint flags in the getView method as the views move in and out of view.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of a view is reused. You need to store the position OR id of that object and provide stroke through effect accordingly. Hope it will help you out. For code reference or help please refer below link.It will definitely help you out

http://lalit3686.blogspot.com/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/896462/Android-Need-to-save-checkbox-state-in-a-custom-ad

Comment: i updated my post, is that correct code? because i still have error